# A list of the 01's in the corporate bonds

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond, credit-risk, credit

I have frequently heard terms like [DV01](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dollar-duration.asp), CV01, [PV01](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/whats-the-difference-between-pv01-and-dv01-of-a-bond). Where can I get a list of these glossaries to study? I am not looking for a detailed explanation, just really a list..  Once I have the list, I can look them up to study by myself.

Comment: You have the complete list already, I believe.

Comment: Instead of ‚CV01‘ you may mean ‚CS01‘.

Comment: IL01 if it’s an inflation linked bond?